# Calculate battery life when LEDs are different voltage to the battery.

Tags: batteries

I'm looking to calculate the battery life in hours with the following setup:

1. AAA Battery: 1.2v 950mAh
2. PCB to convert AAA 1.2v to 3.7v
3. Strip of LEDs. Total 16 leds at .24w each. Total 3.84w at 3.7v

What life would i get from the battery in hours roughly?

Thanks!

Comment: Around 5-15 minutes.

Comment: thanks @TomL. Think i better rethink the product then! :) Need a couple of hours at least.

Answer (score 2):

3.84 W at 1.2 V is 3.2 A, more than one AAA NiMH battery can muster. [This datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/PDFs/HR03-1000_EU.pdf) only shows up to 2 A, and the curve isn't pretty.

Note that at such a high load, it's not a 1.2 V battery at all. Internal resistance is significant, which also means it'll heat up.

[image]